# Perform variable replacement after fmt is used

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to do a replacement. My replacement string is stored in a variable named `$var`.

Input is :

```
This is a sample string
which is of multiline
```

variable is:

```
var="this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var
this is var content this is var content this is var content this is
var content this is var content this is var content"
```

variable replacement works:

```
echo "This is a sample string
which is of multiline" |sed -r "/sample/ {n;s/^/ $var/g}"
This is a sample string
 this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var contentwhich is of multiline
```

But when I used `fmt`, variable replacement not working:

```
var=$(echo $var|fmt)
echo "This is a sample string
which is of multiline" |sed -r "/sample/ {n;s/^/ $var /g}"
sed: -e expression #1, char 84: unterminated `s' command
```

**I think it is because of EOL caused by `fmt`, So is there any workaround?**

Reason for using `fmt` : I need to keep the output limited to 80 char per line .

Comment: why not apply fmt after substitution?

Comment: it will change the whole file, need to do for the changes done my me

Comment: `var` contains unescaped newline characters, which you cannot include in a `sed` script. Defining a dynamic script like this is not as straightforward as you might assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following [here](http://rextester.com/GZHOL39274):

```
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.3.46
var="this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var
this is var content this is var content this is var content this is
var content this is var content this is var content"
echo "This is a sample string
which is of multiline" |sed -r "/sample/ {n;s/^/ $var/g}"
```

will result in:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 88: unterminated `s' command
```

This is because `$var` gets expanded to multiline string, so sed parameters look like this:

```
 ... sed -r '/sample/ {n;s/^/ this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var
this is var content this is var content this is var content this is
var content this is var content this is var content/g}'
```

According to [this sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Commands-Requiring-a-newline):

```
Commands within a script or script-file can be separated by semicolons (;) or newlines (ASCII 10).
```

sed interpretes each line as a separate command, so it finds unterminated 's' command.

Lazy workaround is to substitute newline with '\n' in $var:

```
var="this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var
this is var content this is var content this is var content this is
var content this is var content this is var contenat"
var=${var//$'\n'/\\n}       # puff!
echo "This is a sample string
which is of multiline" |sed -r "/sample/ {n;s/^/ $var/g}"
```

The "good" way is to google smth like "substitute pattern by multiline string in bash" and use awk:

```
var="this is var content this is var content this is var content this is var
this is var content this is var content this is var content this is
var content this is var content this is var contenat"
echo "This is a sample string
which is of multiline" | awk -v "r=$var" '/sample/{print;printf r;next;}1'
```